# Angular-Kendoui - two way binding of the treeview datasource

Tags: angularjs, binding, kendo-ui, treeview

I've created the following example:
http://dojo.telerik.com/ACIKe
It is based on kendo's TreeView angular example.

What can be seen here is that the model is not updated when checking/unchecking the checkboxes.

Any idea how to do the two-way binding work here?

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `kendo.data.ObservableArray` instead of the `kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource`

Check this out:
http://dojo.telerik.com/InOQo